# How to block dates in full calendar resource view?

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I'm using fullcalendar resource schedular plugin trial version. I set a month view. I want to disable click event for days [Monday, Wednesday, Thursday and saturaday] of every month. So end-user can't book resources for those days.

[image]

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/business-hours

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to use `selectAllow` function and inside the function write your logic which time to allow and which time to disallow user select on a slot.

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selectAllow